# session in class file

Tags: asp.net, .net, session, httpcontext, state-management

Hi I have a list called Event Source. In that am adding new item. Once i added , the background process takes this newly created id and start importing EventFields in the Specific List.In EventSource list item i have an ECB menu item called Sync and I should not click the Sync until the import completes in the EventField list. My Client not accepted creating a flag field in the "Event Source List". So wanna maintain some flag in session until the import finishes. for me oncei created EventSource and Clicked Sync first time the HttpContex.current is null but next time it is not.But i need to maintain the flag very first time. That import code is written in the class library.How to maintain.If i use static it s cleaing the value or another instances.,

Comment: Windows services don't have an HttpContext.

Answer (score 0):

You may be wording wrong your question but a Windows Service doesn't have an `HttpContext`, you simply can't do that.